# Add / Change h2 tag on magento 2 product page

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a H2 tag on my product page but I am not able to find out how to do it. I want to make the short description my H2 but I am not able to find it. In the old days we just had the view.phtml but in magento 2? The only thing I can find is

catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

Comment: check this :- <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                        <![CDATA[<h2>Description</h2>]]>
                    </argument>

Comment: thanks for the quick reply? do I just add it or replace it?

Comment: add or replace anything...

Comment: Sorry does not work

Answer (score 0):

To change the html format you can call your custom phtml file and make the changes because the attribute.phtml is called for more than one attibute.

so better option is to create your own file and make the html related changes over there.

first you need to override xml file as per your example code.

only thing is that you need to change the template with your custom template.

you can create template phtml file in your custom module as well as in custom theme and add path for the file in xml.

> YourCustomTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_template.phtml">
</referenceBlock>
```

> YourCustomTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom_template.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();

if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}

$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
// if defined as 'none' in layout, do not render
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
    $renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code))
        ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code)
        : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue) :?>
<div class="product attribute <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_className) ?>">
    <?php if ($renderLabel) :?>
        <h2 class="type"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attributeLabel) ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you can modify and customise this file as per your requirement because this file is only affect to your short description not anywhere else.

Hope this solution will help you.

Thank You

Comment: This file is responsible for the rendering of product description and product short description.

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of the short-description to h2 follow this:

The div that is responsible for rendering the short description is the div with class name `.product.attribute.overview`.

[image: The Div]

Target that className and write the following css for that class in your `_module.less` file:

```css
.product.attribute.overview{
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

The result will be the h2 tag as Magento intends:

[image: The result]

To add/remove any content you have to override the file named `attribute.phtml` under the folder `{magento-root}/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Hope this helps.